# Has Superman ever said, "Ouch!"?

Tags: dc, comics, superman

I was playing with my son and when Superman got knocked off a castle I had him say, "Ouch!"

Then I realized, he probably never says ouch. But, I thought maybe there's a chance that he had!

Has Superman ever said "ouch", "ow", or a similar exclamation of pain?

I'm asking for when he's actually in his Superman persona, not Clark Kent, or any other appearance where he may be trying to hide his identity.

I'd also prefer if it were a fully-powered Superman. I have a feeling that a Superman being affected by green Kryptonite has probably said ouch. I really want to know if anything or anyone has been harmful to Supes to actually make him exclaim in pain.

Comment: [Aaaagh!](https://retconpunchdotcom.files.wordpress.com/2013/12/ice-fire-pain-death.png)

Comment: [Urrrrkh!](http://i.imgur.com/nmNgqVO.jpg)

Comment: [Nnh!](https://arousinggrammardotcom.files.wordpress.com/2013/05/supermansubjekt1713.jpg)

Comment: [Uhhh](http://1.bp.blogspot.com/_6xoH967aC00/TQaKeibWBOI/AAAAAAAAbvU/QzT-VI6M8Hc/s1600/reign056-3.jpg)

Comment: @Richard No "Ugh!"? Also, that "Ahh" one has "Nnnng!" too.

Comment: [Gkk. Ahhk! ᵍʰʰᵏ!](http://24.media.tumblr.com/tumblr_m7ts64j2zM1rsksk8o1_1280.jpg)

Comment: @Richard, who is the villain in the comic with "Nnh!"?

Comment: Gaaaaaaaaaaagh!

Comment: @Kat - It's [Subjekt 17](http://dc.wikia.com/wiki/Subjekt-17_(New_Earth))

Comment: Kryptonite-affected Superman says "Ouch!" (and also Oooff!) in [Super Powers Vol. 2 #4](https://dc.fandom.com/wiki/Super_Powers_Vol_2_4); https://i.stack.imgur.com/IlFXk.png

Answer (score 85, accepted):

Superman has indeed said "Ouch!", on the cover of [Superman #106](http://dc.wikia.com/wiki/Superman_Vol_1_106).

> [image]
>
> Lex Luthor creates an alloy that picks up energy Superman uses in his
> super-feats and transmits it to a suit of electronic armor he has
> invented. The suit gives Luthor all of Superman’s powers, but Superman
> defeats him by exposing himself to Kryptonite, which also transmits
> weakness to Luthor’s suit.

In [Supergirl #002](http://www.dccomics.com/comics/supergirl-2011/supergirl-2), when Supergirl punches Superman right in the face.

> [image]

And in [Superman: The Man of Steel #90](https://dc.fandom.com/wiki/Superman:_The_Man_of_Steel_Vol_1_90), when a ghost flies through him

> [image]

Comment: Not bad, but I do find that it's a cover dissatisfying. Cover events often don't actually seem to take place as depicted inside the book.

Comment: @CreationEdge - Give me two minutes and I'll go have a look.

Comment: It seems he's really hurting *himself*, by punching something super strong. Reminds me of that time Batman tried to punch him and he replied, "Do that again and I won't move, and you'll shatter every bone in your hand." Except, that was cool. (Nothing wrong with this as an answer! Just saying.)

Comment: @CreationEdge - He does fight Luthor in the comic. We don't see him hitting him directly, but he does clonk him with a tree and we see him "helpless to stop him"

Comment: @CreationEdge - I've found a non-cover example.

Comment: Oh, that Supergirl one is much better, and not what I was expecting! I bit more sincere, and from her, and not Darkseid or something! I like it!

Comment: I think it's not Superman's body which is in pain here, but rather his ego :)

Comment: @Philipp: Oh....looks like a bit of both, really. :-)

Comment: @Philipp - Getting punched in the chops by Supergirl is gonna hurt, even if you're Superman.

Comment: The New 52 version of Supergirl has anger management issues.

Comment: @CreationEdge hey, where's that Superman quote from?

Comment: @SumanRoy - It's from [Superman: For Tomorrow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/For_Tomorrow_(comics)) (#208, I think). The panel is [here](https://static4.comicvine.com/uploads/scale_super/2/27500/760646-superman_v2__210__of_12____page_14.jpg)

Comment: I think you should edit your answer to include all the links from your comments on the question. They're relevant, and they'll be more visible in an answer. (+1, by the way)

Comment: @Shokhet - He wanted ouch, he got ouch.

Comment: @Valorum "Has Superman ever said "ouch", "ow", or a similar exclamation of pain?"

Comment: I find the question and the fact that you came back 6 years after to edit it really amazing!

Comment: @Taladris - I like to update my older answers. They've changed how the quote formatting looks on the page, if nothing else